# Pivot Observer Column Longer with each Name as a Cell

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a column with observer name as a string: "JohnDoe,JaneDoe". I want to take each name out of that row and have a separate row per name that appears in the observer column. How do I pivot a table longer based on a text string and remove those names into a new cell?

```
data <- structure(list(site = c("tryon_weber", "phelps_pond", "admin_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "phelps_pond", "wood_lab_pond"), date = structure(c(19447, 
19452, 19467, 19480, 19488, 19492), class = "Date"), observer = c("Brandon Hoenig,Rachel Verdi", 
"JohnDoe,JaneDoe", "JohnDoe,JaneDoe", 
"JaneDoe,JohnDoe", "JohnDoe,JaneDoe,BillDoe", 
"BillDoe,JaneDoe,JohnDoe")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `tidyr::separate_longer_delim(data, observer, delim = ",")`